# Node.js game development, client - server data exchange logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I started to build very simple racing game in javascript. Server is powered by node.js and client side by canvas. I coded a car movement logic while i was testing ideas localy. I was able to create very nice and smooth movement logic (it first speeds up until it gets full speed and then slows down when you dont hold key anymore):

```
car = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    velX: 0,
    velY: 0,
    thrust: 1.2
}

if(hold_up) {
    car.velY += car.thrust;
}
if(hold_down) {
    car.velY -= car.thrust;
}
if(hold_left) {
    car.velX += car.thrust;
}
if(hold_right) {
    car.velX -= car.thrust;
}

game_loop() {

    car.velX *= 0.92;
    car.velY *= 0.90;

    car.x -= car.velX;
    car.y -= car.velY;

    draw_car();

    request_next_frame();
}
```

Now i am trying to implement this logic into the game project but i have a little problem understanding how client should communicate with server in terms of movement of a car.

Localy it worked very good beacuse of `requestAnimationFrame()` which provided stable 60 fps and as we all know, it is drawing on canvas synced with screen refresh rate (whenever screen is ready).

Problem:

1. should i calculate and make move localy and send to server my current coordinates every frame (so other players can update my position on the map)?
2. should i send to the server only desire of making a move in particular direction and let server calculate next position and update everyone (including myself) with it?

I am new to the node js server game development and i dont know the right approach to make it "correctly" and to keep smooth visual effect of this logic.

Any help appriciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is read about [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) configuration for websocket. All players for specific game will connected to one socket and information will be transfer to them in real time.

When any player move, client will push required information to other players through WebSocket and then other client will update map in accordingly.

Please let me know if you required any other information in this context.

Comment: to be honest i wanted to use the second approach too. But what i am thinking is this. Server doesnt operate with `requestAnimationFrame()` so which functionality could i use to be sure that data will come in right interval to keep client animation smooth? From what i noticed, setInterval works differently then rAF. Or maybe there is some other function i can use?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend pushing the desire to move to the server instead of calculating it client side. This will prevent your users from cheating by entering commands into the console to move their car to the finish line, for example.